# Properly align numbers with units in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I need to typeset a table comparing, among other things, the temporal resolution of certain datasets. Ordinarily, I would put the common unit into the table header, and only list the values in the table body. However, in this case, some datasets have a resolution of 5 minutes, others of 1 day, which makes the use of the same units awkward (they would either be `5 min` and `1440 min`, or `0.00347222 d` and `1 d`).

I'd like to align these values along the space between the values and units, and ideally I'd like to keep the unit/value pairs as logical entities (i.e. to type `\SI{1}{\day}` or `\SI{5}{\minute}`, as I would in other contexts). It seems the `S` column type provided by `siuntix` doesn't align unit/value pairs provided using the `\SI` command, but centres them.

MWE (I'd like the entries to be aligned along the space between values and units):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S}
\SI{1}{\day}\\
\SI{30}{\minute}\\
\SI{5}{\minute}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`siunitx` may have features for this but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\def\hmm{%
  \def\day{d}\def\minute{min}%
  \def\SI##1##2{$##1\,\makebox[3em][l]{##2}$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hmm}r}
\SI{1}{\day}\\
\SI{30}{\minute}\\
\SI{5}{\minute}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

seems to do what you ask.

Comment: That's a good idea! I've adapted it a bit to use the `\si` macro for typesetting the unit, and defined a new column type that takes a parameter for setting the width of the unit box. `\newcolumntype{U}[1]{>{\hmm{#1}}r}
\def\hmm#1{%
  \def\SI##1##2{$##1$\,\makebox[#1][l]{\si{##2}}}%
}`. Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The standards of good typography do not recommend putting the values and units in the same column: this makes the table cluttered.  The books I've read say that it is better to have a special column for units.  Siunitx have the `s` column for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lsS}
\toprule
Entry & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Units} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value}\\
\midrule
A & \day & 1\\
B & \minute & 30\\
C & \minute & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd go this way but with the columns swapped and appropriate alignment settings to look like one column :-)

Comment: This is smart :)  But I so much used to formal tables where units precede the values...

Comment: It would depend on the real use case. One case where you do need the units is a table of physical constants: the sort of thing you get in a textbook on physics, physical chemistry, _etc._

Comment: @Boris: Thanks for the answer! In general, I'd agree with you, but in this case, I'll consciously choose to break the typographical rule =)

Comment: well, using @JosephWright suggestion above you can put the units just after the numbers :)

Comment: @Boris: True, but I can't keep them as logical units any more, and it'll make my table layout more complicated by introducing a new column that will need to be joined for the header rows.

Comment: Well, you always can say `\def\mySI#1#2{#1&#2}` and then `\mySI{2}{\day}`.