# siunitx in tabular – align different types of data

Tags: tables, siunitx

I made a table with different types of data in a row. I'd like them to align along the decimal comma – as I thought the `S` would do. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{tum}{RGB}{55,113,200}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-all,
            locale = DE,
            range-phrase= -- ,
    }
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\rowcolors{2}{tum!5}{tum!13}
  \begin{tabular}{%
        >{\raggedright}p{5cm}
        S[retain-explicit-plus]
        l
        S    }
\rowcolor{tum}
\centering \textbf{\color{white}{Stoff}}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\color{white}{Toleranz (inkl. Messunsicherheit)}}}\\     
Vitamine            &  \SI{+50}{\percent}   &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{-35}{\percent}} \\
Mineralstoffe       & \SI{+45}{\percent} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{-35}{\percent}} \\
\cellcolor{tum!13}  & \SI{< 10}{\gram}  & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 2}{\gram} \\
\cellcolor{tum!13}  & \SIrange{10}{40}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 20}{\percent} \\
\multirow{-3}{5cm}{Kohlenhydrate, Zucker, Eiweiß, Ballaststoffe} & \SI{> 40}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 8}{\gram} \\
 \cellcolor{tum!5}  & \SI{< 10}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 1,5}{\gram} \\
\cellcolor{tum!5}   & \SIrange{10}{40}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 20}{\percent} \\
\multirow{-3}{5cm}{Fett} & \SI{> 40}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 8}{\gram} \\
 & \SI{< 4}{\gram}  & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 0,8}{\gram}\\
\cellcolor{tum!15}\multirow{-2}{5cm}{gesättigte FS, ein- und mehrfach unges. FS} & \SI{\geq 4}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 20}{\percent} \\
\cellcolor{tum!5}   & \SI{< 0,5}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 0,15}{\gram} \\
\multirow{-2}{5cm}{Natrium} &\SI{< 4}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 20}{\percent} \\
 & \SI{< 0,5}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 0,375}{\gram}\\
\cellcolor{tum!13} \multirow{-2}{5cm}{Kochsalz}& \SI{\geq 1,25}{\gram} & pro 100 g: & \SI{\pm 20}{\percent}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Properly align numbers with units in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52309/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: How should the ranges in the second column be aligned with respect to the other entries`Do you also want to vertically align the units? Also, why are some uncertainties given in grams, whiel others are expressed in percent?

Comment: @leandris, they should be aligned with the coma. The ranges can just be centered, that's not important. The units are different, because it's a table from a law and some guys thought that it's a good idea this way... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different ersions of your table. Maybe one of then suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{tum}{RGB}{55,113,200}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-all,
            locale = DE,
            range-phrase= -- ,
    }
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\rowcolors{2}{tum!5}{tum!13}
  \begin{tabular}{%
        >{\raggedright}p{5cm}
        r@{\,\,\,}
        S[table-format=2.2]@{\,\,\,}
        l
        l
        r@{\,\,\,}
        S[table-format=2.3]@{\,}
        l}
\rowcolor{tum}
\centering \textbf{\color{white}{Stoff}}   & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{\color{white}{Toleranz (inkl. Messunsicherheit)}}}\\     
Vitamine            &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\SI{+50}{\percent}}   &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\SI{-35}{\percent}} \\
Mineralstoffe       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\SI{+45}{\percent}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\SI{-35}{\percent}} \\
\cellcolor{tum!13}  & $<$ & 10 & \si{\gram}  & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 2 & \si{\gram} \\
\cellcolor{tum!13}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\numrange{10}{40}} & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$& 20 & \si{\percent} \\
\multirow{-3}{5cm}{Kohlenhydrate, Zucker, Eiweiß, Ballaststoffe} & $>$ & 40 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$&  8 &  \si{\gram} \\
 \cellcolor{tum!5}  & $<$ & 10 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 1,5 & \si{\gram} \\
\cellcolor{tum!5}   & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\numrange{10}{40}} & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ &  20& \si{\percent} \\
\multirow{-3}{5cm}{Fett} & $>$ & 40& \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 8 & \si{\gram} \\
 & $<$ & 4& \si{\gram}  & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 0,8& \si{\gram}\\
\cellcolor{tum!15}\multirow{-2}{5cm}{gesättigte FS, ein- und mehrfach unges. FS} & $\geq$ & 4 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 20 & \si{\percent} \\
\cellcolor{tum!5}   & $<$ & 0,5 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ & 0,15 & \si{\gram} \\
\multirow{-2}{5cm}{Natrium} & $<$ & 4 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ &  20 & \si{\percent} \\
 & $<$ & 0,5 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ &  0,375 & \si{\gram}\\
\cellcolor{tum!13} \multirow{-2}{5cm}{Kochsalz}& $\geq$ & 1,25 & \si{\gram} & pro 100 g: & $\pm$ &  20 & \si{\percent}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}{%
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
        S[table-format=>2.2,retain-explicit-plus,table-space-text-post = \si{\percent},table-align-text-post = true]
        S[table-format=-2.3,table-space-text-post = \si{\percent},table-align-text-post = true]    }
\toprule
Stoff  & {Toleranz} & {Messunsicherheit}\\ \midrule     
Vitamine            &  +50\si{\percent}   &  -35\si{\percent} \\ \addlinespace
Mineralstoffe       &  +45\si{\percent} & -35\si{\percent} \\
\cmidrule{3-3}
& & {pro \SI{100}{\gram}}\\ \cmidrule{3-3}
\multirow{2}{=}{Kohlenhydrate, Zucker, Eiweiß, Ballaststoffe}  & < 10\si{\gram}   & 2 \si{\gram} \\
  & \numrange{10}{40}\si{\gram} & 20 \si{\percent} \\
 & > 40\si{\gram} &  8\si{\gram} \\ \addlinespace
Fett  & < 10 \si{\gram}  & 1,5\si{\gram} \\
   & \numrange{10}{40}\si{\gram}  & 20\si{\percent} \\
 & > 40 \si{\gram}  & 8\si{\gram} \\ \addlinespace

\multirow{2}{=}{gesättigte FS, ein- und mehrfach unges. FS}  & <  4 \si{\gram} &  0,8 \si{\gram}\\
 & \geq 4  \si{\gram} &  20  \si{\percent} \\ \addlinespace
Natrium   & < 0,5  \si{\gram} &  0,15  \si{\gram} \\
 &< 4  \si{\gram}&  20  \si{\percent} \\ \addlinespace
Kochsalz & < 0,5  \si{\gram} &   0,375  \si{\gram}\\
& \geq  1,25  \si{\gram} & 20  \si{\percent}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```